# Geometric series of matrices, left and right multiplying

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices

Let A and M be square matrices of the same size. Assuming that the following serries converges, what is its sum?

$M+AMA^T + A^2M{A^T}^2+\ ... $

I suspect that the sum can be expressed by a closed formula similar to the classical formula for geometric series with scalars.

Edit:
I am not sure if that helps but: $M$ is symetric positive definite, $A$ is invertible, $A^iM(A^T)^i$ is symetric positive definite and the sum is also symetric positive definite. I don't mind if you use some additional assumptions. But I would realy appretiate solutiuon using matrix algebra.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X = M + AMA^T + A^2M(A^T)^2 + \dotsb$

Multiply on the left by $A$ and the right by $A^T$:
$$ AXA^T = AMA^T + A^2M(A^T)^2 + A^3M(A^T)^3 + \dotsb = X-M $$
so
$M = X-AXA^T.$
Interestingly, I don't think it's actually possible to find a solution to this in matrix form. It's a linear equation, so it's obviously solvable, but maybe not without resorting to components.

Comment: Can some additional assumptions help to find solution in matrix form? I edited the question and added the assumptions from my motivation problem. And I don't mind if some other additional assumptions are added.

Comment: So $\operatorname{vec}{M} = (I-(A\otimes A))\operatorname{vec}{x}$, which is not solvable for all $A$. If $I-A\otimes A$ is invertible, though, then there you go.